# Magento addComplexSuccessMessage on admin module

Tags: magento2, messages

I'm trying to use the addComplexSuccessMessage function on admin custom module, but I get an empty message.

The code I have is the following:

/etc/di.xml

```
    <!-- Admin HTML Complex Messages -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\MessageConfigurationsPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurationsMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="createDocumentSuccessMessage" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="const">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\Renderer\BlockRenderer::CODE</item>
                    <item name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Invoicing_Moloni::messages/createDocumentSuccessMessage.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

view/adminhtml/templates/messages/createDocumentSuccessMessage.phtml

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>

<?= $block->escapeHtml(__(
    'Document was sucessefuly created: <a href="%1">Open document</a>.',
    $block->getData('document_url')),
    ['a']
);
```

Controller/Adminhtml/Documents/Create.php

```
$this->messageManager->addComplexSuccessMessage(
            'createDocumentSuccessMessage',
            [
                'document_url' => $this->_url->getUrl('document/url')
            ]
        );
```

I can't seem to understand why I get this empty message: 
[image]

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a couple things I was doing wrong. 
First, the messages folder must be inside the adminhtml/templates; 
Second, I was editing the etc/di.xml while I should be adding that code to etc/adminhtml/di.xml

For all that have some problems with complexMessages, I'll leave this post :)

Comment: I am still getting the plain text of anchor tag in addComplexSuccessMessage. I have followed the same way provided by you. I am using Magento 2.3.4.

Comment: Don't be like me and forget to run setup:di:compile after you change di.xml...